# which files can be deleted to save space

Tags: windows-10, disk-space, tree, space

I have scanned my C drive with TreeSize tool.
Here is a screenshot.
[image: tree size tool scan]

I want to know which files I can delete to save space.
I am on Windows 10.

Comment: [Disk cleanup in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4026616/windows-10-disk-cleanup)

Answer (score 2):

The safest general advice is simply to use the Disk Cleanup utility included with Windows.

This will clear the standard things and will not damage your system.

Besides this, what *can* be deleted will depend on what is on your computer.

Based only on the screenshot (which doesn't tell us much) a lot of your disk space is used up in your User folders, which is good. Those are mostly files you placed yourself and so can move or remove without damaging the system.

Answer (score 0):

Your space is taken up in USERS (normal) and page / hiber files. Do not delete the latter as they have been set up at some point and needed.

Windows 10 1909 and beyond, set up storage delete. Start, System, Storage and set up thresholds and days.

In C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Temp, delete what you can (most will delete, some are in use).

In C:\Windows\Temp, same as above. If Windows tells you that you need permissions, grant permission to open the folder.

Now use Disk Cleanup. When it starts, select Clean up System Folders, and it runs again. Then select All Items in the selection box, OK, and allow it to finish. If it wants to delete Windows.old and your system is working properly, allow that.

When all is done, do a final restart and check disk space now versus before.

If you need more space relief, look in document, pictures, movies and like places and back old files off to an external USB Hard or SSD Drive.

Comment: Disk Cleanup takes care of all of those already, and you're assuming the most space is being used in app data when it's just as likely OP has large downloads or other files in their profile, or another profile on the system, taking up that space.

Comment: Often yes, very large new temp files are usually left behind because of date.  That is why I suggest a review